# AngularJS input url invalid/valid/error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input

I've a mistake with input type url in angularjs. I would disable the button if input is empty or invalid and I wrote the code below. Well, it's fine on the first time o if I write an incorrect url but if it's empty propForm.imgUrl.$invalid and propForm.imgUrl.$error.url it returns me false and this enable click of button

```
    <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="url" name="imgUrl" ng-model="$parent.urlImage" class="form-control">
            </div>
                <div class="pull-right col-sm-2">
                   <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" ng-disabled="propForm.imgUrl.$invalid || propForm.imgUrl.$pristine || propForm.imgUrl.$error.url" ng-click="addImage()">Add</a>
                 </div>
```

Where is the trick?a

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is adding `required` to `input` please see demo below.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {




});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">

    <form name="propForm">
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="url" name="imgUrl" ng-model="$parent.urlImage" class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right col-sm-2">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" ng-disabled="propForm.imgUrl.$invalid || propForm.imgUrl.$pristine || propForm.imgUrl.$error.url" ng-click="addImage()">Add</a>
      </div>


    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```